# DAYS and DATE clause in DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am wondering if someone could explain this line of code of DB2 in Java, especially the function of DAYS clause since typically I saw it being used like DAYS(xxx):

```
dd.actual_date between DATE('"+startDate+"') - "+noDays+" DAYS AND DATE('"+startDate+"')
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Date(String s) might be the construtor which is now deprecated. I am not sure of DAYS(). Is this part of the statement? Can you paste the whole statement?

Comment: This is one line of a very long query.

Comment: Please note that the use of `BETWEEN` is often frowned upon, as it (usually) creates _inclusive_ ranges (`a <= x <= b`).  Generally speaking, it's considered better to create an exclusive range for the upper bound (`x >= a AND x < b`), especially for things like timestamps (where generating the correct inclusive upper bound can be difficult/lengthy).  This avoids a type of fencepost error.  Also, you're doing string concatenation - please watch out for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [IBM DB2 infocenter: Date Arithmetic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_datearithmetic.htm), this syntax can be used to add or subtract days (or months or years) from dates. The query will be something like this:

```
 dd.actual_date between DATE('20120801') - 3 DAYS 
                    AND DATE('20120801')
```